# I want to display "$ key" in the home.html page To make sure the code works, it shows a line of "snapshotChanges ();" in ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, node.js, firebase, ionic-framework

This code not working in project.html

$key in html not work

```
<p>{{shopadd.$key}}</p>
```

Import this file from project.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController ,NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AngularFireDatabase , AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';

import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class HomePage {

shop : AngularFireList<any>;
shopadd : Observable<any[]>;
constructor(public navCtrl:NavController,public db:AngularFireDatabase,public navParams: NavParams,public auth: AngularFireAuth
){
this.shopadd = this.db.list('market').valueChanges();
this.shopadd = this.shop.snapshotChanges();


  }}
```

I want select data $key in firebase

Answer (score 0):

these two statements don't return a single object

```
this.shopadd = this.db.list('market').valueChanges();
this.shopadd = this.shop.snapshotChanges();
```

[From the angularfire documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#angularfireaction---action-based-api)

> **valueChanges()**
>
> What is it? - Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects. All Snapshot metadata is stripped and just the method provides only the data.

And

> **snapshotChanges()**
>
> What is it? - Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of AngularFireAction[].

```
this.marketItems = this.db.list('market').snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(results => 
    results.map(r => ({ key: r.payload.key, ...r.payload.val() }))
  )
);
```

Somwhere in your html...

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of marketItems | async">
        {{item.key}} 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thinks for you Aaron saunders

Comment: I want delete item in firebase html and ts